# Sync playing AKSamplerMetronome and AKAppleSequencer

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, midi, audiokit

Thanks for AudioKit !
I have next question:
I'm trying to get ideal sync playing of AKSampleMetronome and one midi file wrapped in AKMIDISampler. Here is my code:

```
let metronome = AKSamplerMetronome()
let mixer = AKMixer()
let midiSampler = AKMIDISampler()
midiSampler.samplerUnit.loadSoundBankInstrument(....)
metronome >>> mixer
midiSampler >>> mixer
AudioKit.output = mixer
AudioKit.start()
let sequencer = AKAppleSequencer(filename: "midifilename")
sequencer.enableLooping()
sequencer.tracks[1].setMIDIOutput(midiSampler.midiIn)
//now play
sequencer.play()
metronome.beatTime = 0
metronome.play()
```

But when I'm changing tempo like this:

```
sequencer.setTempo(bpm)
let now = AVAudioTime(hostTime: mach_absolute_time())
metronome.setTempo(Double(bpm), at: now)
```

After a while the sound of metronome and midi sequencer diverges.
How can I achieve accurate solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this but I would make one of the tracks in the sequencer a metronome track and send that midi signal to a midiSampler.

Comment: Cool, Thank you! So if I want to create full track metronome in looping should I use sequencer.length.beats (of midi file track) number for creating metronome notes ? And how can I use wav files for playing theese metronome clicks (can I) ?